# How to trigger redux action when there is a single radio button

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

In the majority of the cases, I will have an array of objects which are rendered as radios where only one can be selected, which triggers a redux/saga action.

This all works perfectly fine if there is a user interaction (selecting the radio) but now I'd like to auto select that radio ONLY if there is a single entry in the list. I've tried to call the function that triggers the action but I end up in the endless loop.

Comment: You'll probably need to add some example code that reproduces the issue

Comment: I know, the challenge is to copy/paste without breaking my contract :) Theoretically, it should be possible to invoke action within other action if I see that there is only one entry. that is not a violation of 'redux-saga' principles right??